# TFS Proxy + Local Build + TFS Server

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I will brief the project context. Our project has two development centers in two countries. 
In the main office (On Shore),Team Foundation Server(TFS 2010) has been setup and developers from offshore(Offshore) connect to  this Server via VPN connection. All deployment (Production and testing) environment is setup only in On Shore.

However, offshore team needs to create a deployment environment in their country where it should be same as deployment environment in On Shore.

So, we thought of creating a TFS Proxy in offshore and It connect to On Shore TFS server.

Questions:

1. What is the best approach for offshore developers to check in their code ? i.e where the should check in the code either TFS server in On Shore or TFS proxy in Off Shore?
2. If the answer for first question is TFS Proxy, and how can we synchronous TFS main server and proxy without merging conflicts.
3. What would be the best approach to configure the local build using TFS Proxy in offshore ?

Thanks in advance for your help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS Proxy is only used for "gets" so there are no merge conflicts to resolve.  You just need to setup the proxy address in Visual Studio and it will automatically do gets via the proxy, and check-ins to the main TFS server: [How to: Configure Team Foundation Version Control to use Proxy Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245478.aspx)

However, if your VPN endpoint is Onshore, then setting up an Offshore Proxy isn't going to help you since all traffic has to be routed through the Onshore location via VPN anyways.